# sqlcmd running into unicode conversion issues on SLES12SP5

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, sles

I have a SLES12-SP5 docker container running and I followed the instructions here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#suse17 to install mssql-tools.

When i try running mssql-tools, I get the following error:

```
c1dd384365b5:/ # /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Can't initiate unicode conversion.
```

Is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: Broken iconv? Non-ASCII characters in your password?

Comment: I am not evening reaching to the part where i am entering the SQL Server password. As far as iconv is concerned i have version 2.22 installed on my container.:

c1dd384365b5:/ # /usr/bin/iconv --version
iconv (GNU libc) 2.22
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Ulrich Drepper.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the package `glibc-locale` is installed. You can also check the output of the `locale` command.

Before:

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
...
```

After:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error if the driver does not exist on the deployment machine or there are problems with its installation.

Install/Reinstall the *Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server* ODBC Driver

Official Microsoft Download link (Windows, Linux, OSX): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567

Documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

So to potentially save some random Googler a lot of time and research...

The Microsoft ODBC driver uses glibc gconv to convert character sets. However there is no dependency on the package and the driver simply fails with the error "`[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unicode conversion failed`", if the necessary gconv modules are not installed!

On some operating systems, the `glibc` package already contains all the necessary gconv modules to convert from the typical character sets, however on other operating systems only ANSI C UTF-8 support is built-in and the other gconv modules are provided by the `glibc-gconv-extra` package.

TL;DR the fix is install `glibc-gconv-extra` .

This could be considered a bug in the Microsoft ODBC driver because of the missing dependency, however it's true that change in the packages is relatively recent.